# Perl script authorindex

Tags: authorindex

I'm trying to run the Perl `authorindex` script on my `main.aux` file. Yet, when I run it, I get the message

> You must specify at least one BibTeX database.

Within the `main.tex` I included:

```latex
\usepackage{authorindex}
\bibliography{library.bib}
```

I found the following code to which this may apply, but I have no idea how to solve this:

```perl
my $bibfiles=join(",",@bib)
  || die "You must specify at least one BibTeX database\n";
print AUXFILE "\\bibdata{$bibfiles}\n";
```

Comment: Unrelated: Bibliographies are usually not listed with the `.bib` extension in the argument to `\bibliography`

Comment: Also note that on the site we prefer complete (but minimal) self contained examples. That makes it a lot ewasier to test an issue without having to guess what the user is doing.

Comment: ... ahh, yes, it might also be need to use `\aicite` instead of `\cite` (can be overloaded in the preamble, see the manual